# Azure Table Storage - GUID coming back empty

Tags: azure, deserialization, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am trying to retrieve some entities from a table. I am successfully able to get back strings but when I try to get GUID, it comes back empty (all zeros).

```
[DataContract]
public class myEntity : TableEntity
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ID")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }

}
```

...

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(conStr);
var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tblName);
TableQuery<myEntity> query = new TableQuery<myEntity>().Where(string.Empty);
```

How do I get the correct value of GUIDs in table storage? Is it related to TableEntity.ReadEntity?

Comment: Please edit your question to show a sample of your data, including guid (maybe it's improperly formatted?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any extra operation required to get GUID properties. Have you cross checked by other tools if there is indeed values stored in GUID propeties of that table?

Comment: thanks for the follow up and yes, i did. I used Azure management studio and I can see valid GUIDs in that column

Comment: from looking at the table with Azure Management studio, I see the type is GUID. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you try DynamicTableEntity type? It stores the properties in a dictionary. If you could put the dictionary value here, I can provide more help.

Comment: OK, your last comment helped solve it in a differnt way. I am still unsure why the strongly typed way did not work but results achieved and I am out of time here. I used: var entities = table.ExecuteQuery(new TableQuery()).ToList(); and entities[i].Properties.TryGetValue("ID", out ep); and ep?.GuidValue.ToString(). Works!

Comment: The root cause is clear. Your property name in the strong type class is "Id", but actually the GUID is stored in Azure Storage as "ID". Property names in Azure Storage Table are case sensitive.

Comment: unfortunately, I do not share the same clarity with you as I tried with all cases and it still did not get me the result I was looking for. Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

@RotemVaron, you can use the function [`TableEntity.ReadEntity Method (IDictionary<String, EntityProperty>, OperationContext)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj717648.aspx) to deserializes the entity using the specified `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` that maps property names to typed [`EntityProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.entityproperty.aspx) values. Then, getting the Guid value from the EntityProperty object.

There is a [blog](http://fabriccontroller.net/dictionarytableentity-working-with-untyped-entities-in-the-table-storage-service/) shows the sample `Reading existing entities` which traverse the properties include `GuidValue` from entity.

Comment: thanks for the follow-up. It helped me zero down on this issue. Specifically, EntityProperty.GuidValue